# Area Between Two Curves ($y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was asked to find the area between two curves: $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$. I used the interval $[0,1]$, which I found by substituting $x$ in one of the equations. I came up with this: $2\displaystyle\int_0^1\sqrt{x}dx - \int_0^1x^2 dx = 1$. However, the book says the answer is $\frac{1}{3}.$ What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why did you come up with a $2$ in front?

Comment: If you remove the $2$ in the front of the first integral, you will get the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\max(x^2, \sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Take $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x} dx - \int_{0}^1 x^2 dx$
$$=\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{x} - x^2 dx$$
$\int x^{1/2} dx = x^{1/2+1} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+1} = x^{3/2} \frac{2}{3}$

and $\int x^2 dx = x^{2+1} \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3} x^3$
$$=\frac{2}{3} 1^{3/2} - \frac{1}{3} 1^3 - (\frac{2}{3} 0^{3/2} - \frac{1}{3} 0^3)$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Why did you multiply the first integral by $2$? Note that the area between two curves are asked and area above $x = y^2$ on fourth region should not be counted to area between two curves.

Comment: Yeah, this was the point I was confused about. My thought process was that I had to find the absolute value of the area between $\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$

Comment: I'm glad that it is clear now.